# bad character XML files and etree in python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, invalid-characters

I have xml files that I get xml character error for some. Example:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: invalid character in attribute value, line 4, column 41976
```

I've read tons of things and tried them nothing helped. I would be interested to know solutions like this:

1- I read all xml files in folder, so for many of them it passes for some it stops. How can I ignore the stop in Python?
2- How can I fix the problem for the input files giving me error?

Sample code:

```
tree = etree.parse(sys.argv[1]+file)
for extraction in tree.findall("TIMEX3"):
    value=""
    for token in extraction.findall("TOKEN"):
         value = value + " " + token.text
```

error:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: invalid character in attribute value, line 4, column 41976
```

tried this: https://gist.github.com/lawlesst/4110923
Didn't work. It actually created problem over the correct files as well.

I also checked character 41976 and it is totally a good character.

```
head -4 file.xml | tail -1 | head -c 41977
```

this is the result: last characters of the result:

```
numchild="0" numbsibling="0"
```

Thanks.

Comment: For 1, it's hard to say without knowing what the invalid character is (or I guess, what lxml *thinks* the invalid character is).  For 2, you could just wrap the processing inside a `try` block, and add an `except` handler for `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError` where you print a note, and continue on your way.  Make sure this try block is *inside* the loop you're using to iterate over your filenames.

Comment: I tried: `try:
        tree = etree.parse(sys.argv[1]+file)
    except etree.XMLSyntaxError as e:
        print e`. so it's now good!

Comment: and you did `from lxml import etree`?  Does what you tried not work?

Comment: now i can skip the files with error! but can't do anything with them.

Comment: Right, you'll need to address the root cause of the exception in the first place.  The try/except block was just to allow you to continue processing the other files despite running into an exception.